# Aurelia - Custom element property binding resolution

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia

I have created a custom element with an `@bindable` property. In the element's constructor another property is set using the value of the bound property. This is the code for the custom element (file name `custom-element.ts`):

```
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class CustomElement{

  @bindable value: any = null;
  message: any;

  constructor(){
    this.message = this.generateMessage();
  }

  generateMessage(){
    if (this.value != null){
      // logic to generate and return message
    } else {
      return "Someting went wrong";
    }
  }
}
```

This model has a the simple related view (file name `custom-element.html`):

```
<template>
  The value id is: ${value.id}, and the message is: ${message}
</template>
```

I use this element in a view elsewhere, whose model has access to the `value` object:

```
<require from="resources/custom-element"></require>
<custom-element value.bind="value"></custom-element>
```

While `${value.id}` displays correctly, the `${message}` is always `Something went wrong`.

When is `value` being set, and how can I use its value to set `message`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is called when your custom element is initally created however the data-binding will happen later in its lifecycle.

In order to get access to the bound properties you need to use the [`bind` lifecycle callback](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#extending-html) (or `attached` depending on your actual needs) to set your `message`:

```
export class CustomElement{

  @bindable value: any = null;
  message: any;

  bind() {
    this.message = this.generateMessage();
  }

  generateMessage(){
    if (this.value != null){
      // logic to generate and return message
    } else {
      return "Someting went wrong";
    }
  }
}
```

As an alternative solution you can subscribe on your `value` property changed event with implementing a method with the naming convention: `yourPropertyChanged` (so in your case `valueChanged`) and do the message generation there:

```
valueChanged(newValue) {
  this.message = this.generateMessage(newValue);
}

generateMessage(newValue){
  if (newValue != null){
    // logic to generate and return message
  } else {
    return "Someting went wrong";
  }
}
```